# Vuex (Vue3) unable to transmit payload

Tags: vuejs3, vuex, getter

I have removed the methods that are not involved in the case for a more concise display.
Need to return the `count` value for the object with the specified `id`. When I pass a valid `id` to `counter`, the console seems to display the entire getters instead of the transmitted identifier.

Component:

```
props: {
  id: Number,
},
methods: {
  ...mapGetters([
    'getBasketItemCountsById',
  ]),
},
computed: {    
  counter() {
    return this.getBasketItemCountsById(this.id /* 1 */)
  },
},
```

Vuex store:

```
import {createStore} from "vuex";

const store = createStore({
    state() {
        return {
            /* id, price, title, count */
            basket: [
                { id: 1, price: 100, title: 'some title', count: 1},
            ],
        }
    },
    getters: {
        getBasketItemCountsById(state, id) {
            const founded = state.basket.find(x => x.id === id);
            console.log([id, founded])
            return founded !== undefined ? founded.count : 0
        }
    },
});

export default store;
```

Console log:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

[Getters](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html#property-style-access) in Vuex do not accept additional arguments. They were meant to return a computed value according to the current state.

In your code, the `id` prop actually [is the whole getter object](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html#property-style-access). Using that, you can access other getters' functions in the current getters.

To address your issue, the [*Method-Style Access*](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html#method-style-access) provides you custom search by `id`. It takes advantage of [the **currying** style](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/what-is-currying-function-in-javascript/).

```js
getters: {
    getBasketItemCountsById: state => id => {
        const founded = state.basket.find(x => x.id === id);
        console.log([id, founded])
        return founded !== undefined ? founded.count : 0
    }
},
```

Here, instead of returning a simple and computed value from getters (they were designed this way) another function is returned. The returnee function can accept as many arguments as it needs, or even return another function to extend the currying.

** The rest of your code stays untouched.

Comment: unfortunately, this won't work on Vue 3 with Veux, I tried this approach – it returns the function body as text